# Spacebar for PLAY/STOP in Quicktime not working in Ventura M1, MacBookAir

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, quicktime, ventura

In Ventura M1 MacBookAir the spacebar does not work. I often use Quicktime to quickly edit videos, and this feature is very important. I can't seem to find how to assign a key shortcut to this functionality. Any help welcome!

Comment: It works for me, on two Macs. Do you have anything that might interfere with the keyboard? Does Space work in Music, TV, other apps?

Comment: Thanks benwiggy. Spacebar works fine in those other apps! Is there a trick I can use to assign this shortcut in my Mac?

Comment: It's defined by default; so the question is: why isn't it working? Can you try creating a brand new user account, and see if Space works in QuickTime there? (NB: This is a test, not a solution.) If it works in the new account, then the problem is *something* in your old user account, like a preference, some app that loads in the background, etc. I presume you have restarted, just to rule out a mad glitch?

Comment: Double check that you  have Full Keyboard Access turned OFF in Accessibility settings.

Comment: I enabled the guest account and the same (can't use spacebar). My Full Keyboard Access is turned off (something I had read online and checked earlier). Thanks for the tips though.